# Как правильно реализовать красивый url

Tags: url, php, оптимизация

На будущем сайте у меня урл страницы той или иной новости описывается в виде:

```
/news/?id=666
```

На хэш-коде (и не только) мне настоятельно посоветовали использовать запись в виде:

```
/news/666-interesnaya-novost
```

Как теперь мне правильно реализовать такую конструкцию? У меня в БД есть поле с названием новости на русском языке. Наверное, теперь я должен ввести еще одно поле с латинским аналогом, которое и будет фигурировать в урл? Или я иду заведомо ложным путем?

Comment: просто в транслит переводите, http://www.php.net/manual/en/transliterator.transliterate.php

Comment: Дополнительное поле в таблице. При формировании урла брать id-url . В .htacces сделать разделение для передачи роутеру формата /news/([0-9]{1,3})-([a-z-]{1,35}) index.php?cat=new&newsID=$1 [L].
Также если сайт не имеет большую посещяемость (десятки тысяч в сутки) можно убрать числовое значение и использовать чпу. Делал интернет магазин с таблицей почти 80 млн записей. Для каждой строки был сформирован уникальный урл. Поле varchar с проставленным индексом. При посещяемости в среднем 5-6 тысяч человек в сутки, страницы формировались шустро.

Comment: @eicto, если динамически переводить в транслит, то, наверное, динамически созданный адрес не сможет сослаться в дальнейшем на данную страницу, т.е. такой адрес нельзя будет использовать в качестве ссылки...

Comment: @terantul, спасибо, наверное так оно и есть. Только я не использую регулярку в .htaccess - все запросы просто направляются на index.php, а далее тот или иной контроллер на свое усмотрение ищет необходимую информацию в REQUEST_URI

Comment: @eicto, а за встроенную функцию транслитерации спасибо!

Comment: @eicto, упс, в php 5.3 такого класса и функции нет? (((